# Save Data using One to Many relationshiop

Tags: relationship, laravel-8

I have several answers for a question. My question input filed is like below.

```
<input name="question" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Place your question here">
```

I am adding multiple answers dynamically. My answer input field is like below.

```
<input name="answer[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Place your answer here">
```

I made question Table using these columns  'id','question','created_at','updated_at'.

I made answer Table using these columns  'id','question_id','answer','created_at','updated_at'.

I am using below code to save Question and Answers.

```
public function add_form(Request $request)
    {        
        $question = Question::create(['question' => request()->input('question')]);

        $question->answers()->create([request()->input('answer')]);
    }
```

I am getting below error.

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'answer' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `answers` (`question_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (4, 2021-08-05 11:56:16, 2021-08-05 11:56:16))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First map single dimension array to multidimensional array.

```
 $answer=collect(request()->answer)->transform(function ($item){
            return ['answer'=>$item];
        })->toArray();
```

and while saving

```
 $question->answers()->createMany($answer);
```